# Client Certificate Authentication Nginx SSL Pass Through

Tags: docker, nginx, tls1.2, docker-registry, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've set up an NGINX as proxy before a docker registry. The registry uses tls to authenticate users (and is configured properly; I can pull images inside the cluster with the certificate). The nginx is configured like this:

```
 server {
      listen 443;
      server_name default_server;

      #charset koi8-r;
      #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

      location / {
        if ($remote_addr != xxx) {
          return 403;
          break;
        }
        proxy_set_header Host $host; 
        proxy_pass https://xxx:xxx;
        break;
      }

      error_page  404              /404.html;  
      error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      }
    }
```

Now, when I try curling with a valid certificate like this:

```
curl -v --key client.key --cert client.cert  xxx:xxx/v2/_catalog
```

I get an `http: TLS handshake error from xxx:xxx: tls: client didn't provide a certificate` error in the docker registry logs. Is the nginx configured properly or is there sth missing? Any ideas on how to debug this further?

The NGINX logs state:

```
[error] 8#8: *65 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate:SSL alert number 42) while SSL handshaking to upstream,
```

Comment: Where did you curl ? The same nginx server?

Comment: my local computer

Comment: Try it : curl -v --key client.key --cert client.cert  xxx:443/v2/_catalog

Comment: This one works: `curl -v -k --key client.key --cert client.cert docker-registry-ip:port/v2/_catalog`

This one doesn't:
`curl -v -k --key client.key --cert client.cert https://localhost:443/v2/_catalog` resulting in `SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

Comment: Change server_name localhost; certificates shoud be owned by domain (localhost or xxx domain ) which you use to curl,  then curl  again

Comment: you mean adding domain certificates configured in nginx? But that would then terminate the ssl session at nginx level..? changing server_name doesn't have any effect, as default_server is wildcard.

Comment: Nginx is reserved proxy. So it will be transfered server_name domain to xxx domain. So you curl domain_you_define_in_server_name:443 --- > to xxx:xxx domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. The passthrough feature works embedded in the stream directive only (which itself must be included outside of http directive). So in the end its quite simple and clean:

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 443;
    allow <IP_TO_BE_ALLOWED>;
    deny all;
    proxy_pass xxx:xxx;
  }
}
```